# Extremely disturbing horror story set in the 1800's about an ancient English haunted grandfather clock

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, horror

The story begins as a man in England receives a clock from a relative who passes away. Fully 7 feet tall and black as coal, it presence makes people uneasy. The aunt's will reports that its made of bog wood, and that the face and the hands of the clock are made of the bones of an extremely ancient man from the bog. The story only gets better and the ending is disturbing in the extreme. Nowadays I look closely at grandfather clocks !

Comment: Huh, I didn’t edit the title, but the edit said that I did. It’s the grandfather clock’s doing! Run for your lives!!

Comment: yes but 7 ft tall haunted clocks run faster

Comment: Touché. Maybe I should eye my grandma’s grandfather clock more closely next time I look at it...

Comment: 100 ghastly little ghost stories has a grandfather clock horror story

Comment: Welllll okay. The clock is placed in the downstairs hall. At 3 am after the clock strikes, strange sliding and bumping noises are heard. The noises mount the stairs, come to  the mans door and makes noise. He stays inside. Then the maid is up late and begins to retire just as the clock strikes three. Watching the clock like a deer in the headlights, the pendulum door slams open and  she see's a hairy bony bestial arm with claws on its hand swipe at her as she goes by it. With overwhelming fear she looks up at the clock face and beholds a hideous gray face with diabolical eyes leering down

Comment: Yes time frame.  Early England, 1800's I think-

Comment: Could you edit that into the question? Also, are any of the phrases you mentioned ("bestial arm," "diabolical eyes") literally in the story, or are they just description?

Comment: hmmm I do believe they are in the story, hard to remember

Comment: After the clock begins to stalk up and down the stairs, the owner puts it in the garden house. He tells the servants to lock the doors and not open the doors. At 3 the clock slides to the door and begins pounding. the next evening the village priest stops by and say he saw a very tall  terrifying gray creature with toes instead of feet stalking the woods nearby

Comment: @FeyRay That too should be edited into the question.

Comment: [This account](http://www.hotfreebooks.com/book/Byways-of-Ghost-Land-Elliott-O-Donnell.html) seems similar, though it is probably not what you are looking for. A possessed grandfather clock made of bog-oak, with evil gray eyes.

Comment: The [story here](http://trove.nla.gov.au/newspaper/article/64875499) seems even more similar. Bog-oak clock, mobile. It even starts stalking the woods and is spotted by a vicar.

Comment: [This](https://archive.org/stream/somehauntedhouse00odon/somehauntedhouse00odon_djvu.txt) is very likely the account you read, or something much like it. It even mentions a gray creature with "  a  pair of huge, 
toeless, grey feet. "

Comment: What's most disturbing about it is that it's a true story.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Could this be from *[Some Haunted Houses of England and Wales](https://archive.org/stream/somehauntedhouse00odon#page/26/mode/2up)* by Elliott O'Donnell?

[image]

A man receives a clock from his aunt, who has died:

> "You must know," he began, as we sat on deck  watching the lofty
> outlines of St. David's Head slowly  fade in the distance, " you must
> know, O'Donnell,  that after leaving Crawley's I inherited a nice
> little  sum of money from my aunt. Lady Maughan of  Blackrock, who,
> dying quite unexpectedly, left the  bulk of her property to my family.
> My brother Bob  had her estate in Roscommon ; Charley, the house  near
> Dublin ; whilst I— lucky beggar that I am — (for  I was head over
> heels in debt at the time) suddenly  found myself the happy possessor
> of 20,000 pounds and —  a bog-oak grandfather clock."

Note also that the previous paragraph describes the clock as made of "bog-oak."

The clock is jet-black and over seven feet tall:

> Standing at least eight feet high, with a face
> large in proportion [...]
>
> I can't describe to you how  black — black as ebony and shining.

The clock is made of the bones of a man from the bog:

> We did so, and discovered that the frontal pillars  on either side of
> the face of the clock consisted of  two highly polished femur-bones
> which, although  blackened through countless ages of immersion in  the
> bog, and abnormally long (as is inevitably the  case with Paleolithic
> man), were very unmistakably  human.

The owner of the clock removes it to a summer house:

> But I did make one concession : I permitted  them to remove it to the
> summer-house.
>
> My first care now was to see that all the doors  were locked, and
> windows bolted before retiring to  bed ; a precaution that was
> speedily justified.

The creature in the clock is gray, and has no toes on its feet:

> 'And then,' the vicar continued, disregarding  the interruption, '
> it was grey ! — from head to foot  a uniform vivid grey.'
>
> 'A grey monstrosity ! Ah ! now that is interesting ! '
>
> I looked at my uncle quizzically — was he still  joking ? But no !
> he was in sober earnest : could it  be possible he knew anything about
> the clock.
>
> I leaned back in my chair and smiled — feebly.
>
> 'In height," the vicar went on, 'it could not  have been far from
> seven feet, it had an enormous  round head crowned with a black mass
> of shock  hair, no ears, huge spider-like hands and toeless  feet.

Comment: Also available at [Project Gutenberg](http://www.gutenberg.org/ebooks/51568).

Comment: What a spectacularly unprepossessing title.

Comment: FAVORITE PART--<Midnight at length came, in dumb agony she watched .....there were 12 frantic clangs, the pendulum door flew open and an enormous hand, ashy gray, with long malshaped fingers made a convulsive grab at her....glancing up,  the face of the clock had disappeared and in its place she saw a frightful head, gray and evil, large, round, half human half animal and beastly. with abnormally long lidless eyes of pale blue that leered at her in a most sinister manner> I wonder if the aunt died because of the clock, illustrating what could  happen if you didn't escape from the clock.